# Travis-CI: deploy different branches to different servers

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, travis-ci, cloud-foundry

Currently I'm trying to setup a concept project for Continuous Integration using a github repo in combination with Travis-CI.

My.travis.yml looks like this

```
language: java
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
before_cache:
- rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
- rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
cache:
directories:
- "$HOME/.gradle/caches/"
- "$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/"
branches:
 only:
 - master
 - develop

deploy:
 provider: cloudfoundry
 api: https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
 username: j.cuppen@acuity.nl
 password:
  secure: [key]
 organization: 'Acuity\ Stagiairs'
 space: 'stage\ job'
 on:
  repo: JasonLighthunter/GradleTest
  branch: develop
```

and my manifest.yml looks like this:

```
---
applications:
- name: gradleweb
  memory: 512M
  host: gradleTest
  path: build/libs/GradleTest.war
```

Currently when i push to develop it builds and deploys to gradleTest.eu-gb.mybluemix.net

What im trying to figure out is how I can configure travis in such a way that when the master is pushed it is deployed to, let's say: gradleProd.eu-gb.mybluemix.net

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `manifest` file for each deploy. Change your `.travis.yml` to:

```
deploy:
  - provider: cloudfoundry
    edge: true
    username: ${CF_USERNAME}
    password: ${CF_PASSWORD}
    organization: ${CF_ORGANIZATION}
    space: ${CF_SPACE}
    api: https://api.ng.bluemix.net/
    manifest: manifest.master.yml
    on:
      branch: master
  - provider: cloudfoundry
    edge: true
    username: ${CF_USERNAME}
    password: ${CF_PASSWORD}
    organization: ${CF_ORGANIZATION}
    space: ${CF_SPACE}
    api: https://api.ng.bluemix.net/
    manifest: manifest.develop.yml
    on:
      branch: develop
```

in this case you can add two files: `manifest.develop.yml` and `manifest.master.yml`